# How to change overflow of html table elements?

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able scroll td elements (except table side column) as screen size smaller than x size..
To be more clear please check: http://jsfiddle.net/uf32ojm5/7/

How can I scroll only comments fields and let "group" column fixed..

To fix "group" column I have done this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {
  .groupColm{
    position:fixed;
    min-width:100px;
    z-index:1;
  }
}
```

But how do I scroll only comments fields?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `table` sub elements (eg. tr, th, td) cannot be positioned. You may have to look at using `div` elements to "fake" a table layout. This will allow you to position elements as needed at different screen resolutions. My personal preference for css layout framework is http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Do the fix position on <div> and call table inside div like this: <div><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:)

```
div table { display: block; position: relative; width: 100%; }
div tbody { display: block; width:auto; position: relative; overflow-x: auto; white-   
space: nowrap; }
div thead tr { display: block; }
div th { display: block; text-align:left; padding-left:10px; height:50px; line-
height:40px;}
div tbody tr { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
div td {display: block; text-align: left; }
```

live: http://jsfiddle.net/uf32ojm5/12/

Answer (score 0):

I Think you have to put the comments fields in an internal table inside the td and just enable scrolling in the size you need to the content of that td which contain the internal table at that time.

hope my answer help.